# Sort results from get list items

Tags: powershell

I have write some PowerShell script to get double items in different lists. I would like to remove the oldest item. I will check this by the "modified" date. How can I sort the results by "modified" date?

```
#Add SharePoint PowerShell SnapIn if not already added 
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) { 
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" 
} 

$siteCollection = Get-SPSite "https://portal.myCompany.net/teams/siterequests/"

 foreach($spSourceWeb in $siteCollection.AllWebs)
 { 
     $spSourceLists = $spSourceWeb.Lists 

     foreach($spSourceList in $spSourceLists)
     {
         $spSourceList.Items | where {$_['Title'] -eq '440-10011'} | foreach { 
            "modified date: " + $_["Modified"] + " found item: " + $_.Title  + " , in list: " + $spSourceList.Title
         }       
      }
 }
```

So I would like to sort this `$spSourceList.Items | where {$_['Title'] -eq '440-10011'}` on the column "modified". I would like to have the oldest modified date as first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Sort-Object -Property` for sorting the result

```
$spSourceList.Items | where {$_['Title'] -eq '440-10011'} | Sort-Object -Property Modified ....
```

Comment: I try these scripts but the results are the same:

$spSourceList.Items | where {$_['Title'] -eq '440-10011'} | Sort-Object -Property Modified -descending | foreach { 
            "modified date: " + $_["Modified"] + " found item: " + $_.Title  + " , in list: " + $spSourceList.Title
         } 

or

$spSourceList.Items | where {$_['Title'] -eq '440-10011'} | Sort-Object -Property Modified | foreach { 
            "modified date: " + $_["Modified"] + " found item: " + $_.Title  + " , in list: " + $spSourceList.Title
         }

Comment: Try this inside the for each loop `$spSourceList.Items | Sort-Object -Property Modified | Format-Table $_.Title,$_["Modified"]`

Comment: With this last script I got this error: Cannot index into a null array.

Comment: `$spSourceList.Items | where {$_['Title'] -eq '440-10011'} | Sort-Object -Property $_["Modified"]`

Answer (score 1):

I think better solution is to get filtered and sorted items from list using CAML query:

```
$qry = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery;
$qry.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>440-10011</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy>";
$listItems = $spSourceList.GetItems($qry);
```